# Display a variable in parent passed from iframe

Tags: jquery

I am passing a variable from my iFrame to the parent window. In the iframe I have:

```
var recordCount = "<?php echo $totalRows_m;?>";
window.parent.recordCallback(recordCount);
```

In the parent window I have:

```
function recordCallback(recordCount) {
  console.log("RecordCount = " + recordCount);
  $('#Count').html(recordCount);
}
```

Looking at the console I can see the "recordCount" contains my data. Also in the parent window I have:

```
<div id="Count"></div>
```

but the data does not displayon screen. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Do you see any errors in developer console?

Comment: @Ahmad Maleki no errors

Comment: Check that you don 't have multiple items with `id="Count"`, this will only work if the `id` is unique (as it should always be). And check that there is nothing that hides the `div` from view.

Comment: @Peter B thanks Peter, already check that and there is only one item with that id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `recordCallback()` should be retuned as a global variable on both pages. The demo has `index.html` as the parent and `child.html` as child. Due to limitations of Stack snippets, this demo will not function. Review this [PLUNKER](http://embed.plnkr.co/GgKcs8OFDzhAgVZuTvBE/) for a functioning demo.

### index.html

(Parent)
(**This demo does not work. Review [PLUNKER](http://embed.plnkr.co/GgKcs8OFDzhAgVZuTvBE/) instead**)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    label {
      display: block;
      margin-top: 15px;
    }
    
    #out {
      font: 400 28px/1 Consolas;
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    var recordCount;
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Parent Page</h1>
  <label>Record Count: <output id='out'></output></label>
  <iframe id='i1' name='i1' src='child.html'></iframe>

  <script>
    function recordCallback(recordCount) {
      console.log("RecordCount = " + recordCount);
      document.querySelector('#out').value = recordCount;
      return recordCount;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

### child.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    var recordCount = 21;
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Child Page</h1>
  <script>
    recordCount = window.parent.recordCallback(recordCount);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```